# Performing functions on grouped rows in an R dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a large dataframe where multiple rows are repeated measurements for a single ID. I want to return the rows with the maximum value of a column for each individual. Essentially performing a group.by() function as per SQL.

Dataframe (for illustrative purposes)

> ```
> ID lac pO2
> M1 1   80
> M1 4   80
> M2 2   70
> M2 3   70
> M3 3   75
> M3 5   75
> ```

I want to call max(lac) and return the following results.

> ```
> ID lac pO2
> M1 4   80
> M2 3   70
> M3 5   75
> ```

I've had a look around and thought that the by() function might be useful, but haven't had any joy (code below).

```
newdf <- by(df, df$ID, max(df$lac))

Error in FUN(X[[1L]], ...) : could not find function "FUN"
```

I also looked at tapply but this doesn't work because I'm using a dataframe rather than a vector.

```
newdf <- tapply(df, df$ID, max)

Error: "arguments must have same length"
```

I've looked at [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21431321/using-the-ave-function-in-r-count-number-of-unique-months-per-person) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4272735/how-do-i-perform-a-function-on-each-row-of-a-data-frame-and-have-just-one-elemen), but these haven't helped. I'd appreciate some input from people more experienced than I!

**Edit**

Having dug a little deeper I've uncovered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18842894/extracting-rows-of-group-medians-n-r?rq=1) which suggests the plyr package might be useful.

Comment: By and tapply work differently, first argument needs to be in the right format for the function: `tapply(df$lac, df$ID, max)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution using plyr as discussed in update.

Code used was:

```
max_lac <- ddply(.data=df, .variables=.(ID), function(x) 
+ x[which(x$lac == max(x$lac)), ])
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
> by(mtcars, mtcars$cyl, max)
mtcars$cyl: 4
[1] 146.7
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
mtcars$cyl: 6
[1] 258
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
mtcars$cyl: 8
[1] 472
```

Alternatively use `plyr`:

```
> require(plyr)
Loading required package: plyr
> ddply(mtcars, .(cyl), max)
  cyl    V1
1   4 146.7
2   6 258.0
3   8 472.0
```

Comment: Thanks @landroni, I managed to work it out simultaneously to you posting your solution by doing something similar. :)

Answer (score 2):

For large data set try `data.table` (assuming `df` is your data set)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .SD[which.max(lac)], by = ID]

##    ID lac pO2
## 1: M1   4  80
## 2: M2   3  70
## 3: M3   5  75
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `dplyr` alternative in case you're processing large data sets:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(ID) %>% filter(lac == max(lac))

#Source: local data frame [3 x 3]
#Groups: ID
#
#  ID lac pO2
#1 M1   4  80
#2 M2   3  70
#3 M3   5  75
```

Note that in case of multiple rows with maximas in the same group of ID, this function will return *all* rows containing the maximum value in lac, whereas functions using `which.max(.)` will only return the first row containing the maximum (per group).

If you only want to return the first max per group, you can use for example:

```
df %>% group_by(ID) %>% filter(1:n() == which.max(lac))
```

or

```
df %>% group_by(ID) %>% filter(lac == max(lac)) %>% do(head(.,1))
```

Comment: I'm intentionally didn't post this so you won't be mad at me :)

Comment: @DavidArenburg, awesome, you're a real team player ;)

Comment: You also may want to add here that the OP needs to `detach` `plyr` (as it seems like he already using it)

Comment: @DavidArenburg, good point. I can't test right now but I'm guessing that for these functions there wouldn't be an immediate problem with plyr loaded. Also, it's possible to have bother packages loaded if dplyr is loaded after plyr as far as I know (but probably not recommended)

Comment: Thanks @beginneR & @DavidAreburg! I hadn't considered multiple maximal rows for each ID, good point. That may be useful in the future if this pilot study is successful. :)

Answer (score 0):

(if you look at ddply and which.max)
Can it be?:

```
ddply(df,.ID,function(x){x[which.max(x$lac)),]}
```